# error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search

Tags: angularjs, components, angularjs-components

#### AngularJS - Passing data from child component to parent component

I have two AngularJS components, `search` and `form`. `search` is a child of `form`. `search` contains a text input field. I want to send `form` the values inside `search`'s input field.

My approach is bind a function to `search` which will bind the `search` input field to `form`. When AngularJS does try to bind these values, I get the error:

> `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in MyInputValue`.

Is there a better approach to my solution, or did I make a typo somewhere in the code?

### search.component.js

```
class SearchComponentController{}
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('search', {
        bindings: {
            onSearch: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'search.template.html',
        controller: [SearchComponentController]
    });
```

### search.template.html

```
<div>
    <input ng-model="$ctrl.keyword" />
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.onSearch($ctrl.keyword)">Search</button>
</div>
```

### form.component.js

```
class FormComponentController {
    constructor {}
    onSearch(keyword) {
        console.log(keyword);
        // perform logic
    }
}
angular
    .module('app')
    .component('form', {
        templateUrl: 'form.template.html',
        controller: [FormComponentController]
    });
```

### form.template.html

```
<div>
    <search on-search="$ctrl.onSearch()"></search>
</div>
```

### Stack trace

```
script.js:14791 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in MyInputValue
    at fn (eval at compile (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:15642:15), <anonymous>:4:59)
    at SearchComponentController.destination.(anonymous function) [as onSearch] (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:10751:22)
    at fn (eval at compile (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:15642:15), <anonymous>:4:278)
    at callback (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:27463:17)
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:18533:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:18632:25)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:27468:23)
    at defaultHandlerWrapper (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:3785:11)
    at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:9005/js/script.js:3773:9)
```

### The error comes from SearchComponentController.destination

```
case '&':
    if (!optional && !hasOwnProperty.call(attrs, attrName)) {
      strictBindingsCheck(attrName, directive.name);
    }
    // Don't assign Object.prototype method to scope
    parentGet = attrs.hasOwnProperty(attrName) ? $parse(attrs[attrName]) : noop;

    // Don't assign noop to destination if expression is not valid
    if (parentGet === noop && optional) break;

    destination[scopeName] = function(locals) {
      return parentGet(scope, locals);
    };
    break;
```

This switch statement is from [AngularJS 1.6.8](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.8/angular.js) and is called from `initializeDirectiveBindings()` which ets up $watches for isolate scope and controller bindings.

Comment: Show us the entire stack trace for the error

Comment: I have edited my question to include my stack trace

Comment: The error is coming from `SearchComponentController.destination.(anonymous function)`. Show us that code.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code `SearchComponentController.destination.(anonymous function)` (from AngularJS 1.6.8.

Answer (score 2):

use 1/2 way binding instead of &.

```
bindings: {
  onSearch: '<'
},
```

Comment: I don't get an error anymore with one way binding. Instead now I see `undefined` in the console.`onSearch()` is not passing parameters back to the `form` component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Component

```js
angular.module('newsApp').component('newsDetail', {
// ...
bindings: {
  onUpdate: '&' // Two-Way binding to Container
}
// ...
var $ctrl = this;
$ctrl.update = function(id, value) {
  $ctrl.onUpdate({id: id, value: value}); // Arguments must be an Object
};
```

```html
<button ng-click="$ctrl.update(2020, 'foobar')">
  Upgrade
</button >
```

2、Container

```js
angular.module('newsApp').component('newsList', {
// ...
$ctrl.updateNews = function(id, value) {
  list[id] = value;
};
```

```html
<detail ... on-update="$ctrl.updateNews (id, value)"> <!-- Pass to component -->
</detail>
```